# Using dockerfile ADD and COPY commands on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, docker

Is it possible to use the `ADD` and `COPY` commands in a Dockerfile on Mac OS X using boot2docker? If so, how? The naive just gives `No such file or directory`.

So, I've tried two things:

1. having the file in my local directory (same directory as the Dockerfile) on my Mac.
2. scping the file into a specific path on the boot2docker-vm and using ADD from that path.

Neither work.

Edit:

Plain vanilla Boot2Docker Mac OS X version 1.2 clean install.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos
ADD ./some.rpm /tmp/some.rpm
RUN rpm -Uvh /tmp/some.rpm
```

I've tried having `some.rpm` in the same directory as the `Dockerfile`, I've tried having it in `/home/docker` in the `boot2docker-vm` image, I've tried changing `./some.rpm` to `/home/docker/some.rpm`, etc.

Comment: Can you give us more info about your Dockerfile and your setup ?

Comment: Both "answers" here are missing the point that this is on OSX and using boot2docker. If you are on using a Mac, then you probably can't answer this question. Please don't try because having the Linux answers (which are simple) is not helping. On a Mac is is complicated because your docker host is not your local Mac OS. It is a linux running headlessly in a VirtualBox VM. @16mslipry is trying to avoid copying the file to the VM prior to doing the Docker build.

Comment: Considering the [lack of] popularity of OSX in production infrastructure, I'm going to assume this is for local development purposes and not some kind of Continuous Integration system. To get around what I describe in my previous comment, you may want to try putting the file you want to add out on a server (share publicly via Dropbox or github) and get it into your container by adding this to your Dockerfile. `RUN curl -O http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/.../some.rpm `. This is an _alternative_ to your question, that's why I didn't post it as an _answer_.

Answer (score 0):

For using "ADD" in a dockerfile you need two things:
First: a directory with your structure
for example:
./my_docker_dir/some.rpm

Second: a valid Dockerfile in my_docker_dir (it has to be named 'Dockerfile')
        Your line: 'ADD ./some.rpm /tmp/some.rpm' will work

With that prepared you can build your container with 'docker build -t whatever/youwant .'

For more Information read https://docker.readthedocs.org/en/v0.6.3/commandline/command/build/

Comment: You need to [explain better](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) what it is that you're asking in the question and provide a [minimal, verifiable and complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should omit the `./`, so if `some.rpm` is in the same folder as your Dockerfile, try

```
ADD some.rpm /tmp/some.rpm
```

If the file is in a sub-folder called `files` next to your Dockerfile, you can do

```
ADD files/some.rpm /tmp/some.rpm
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple test case for which it works.

Here is the version info for my setup:

```
$ boot2docker version
Boot2Docker-cli version: v1.4.1
Git commit: 43241cb

$ docker version
Client version: 1.4.1
Client API version: 1.16
Go version (client): go1.4
Git commit (client): 5bc2ff8
OS/Arch (client): darwin/amd64
Server version: 1.4.1
Server API version: 1.16
Go version (server): go1.3.3
Git commit (server): 5bc2ff8
```

Here is the test case that you can copy-pasta into your terminal:

```
date > foo.txt
cat > Dockerfile <<EOF
  from centos
  ADD foo.txt /datefile.txt
EOF
docker build -t addtest .
docker run -i -t addtest /bin/cat /datefile.txt
```

It even works if you use the /tmp directory, though I suggest against it since that is supposed to be wiped out on every boot.